# Screenshot not including images using python ghost.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, ghost.py

I am using ghost.py to take a screencapture of a webpage. But the script isn't capturing any of the images on the page. I've set download_images=True - but that doesn't seem to work.

My code:

```
from ghost import Ghost

ghost = Ghost(wait_timeout=4, download_images = True) #download_images not working

ghost.open('http://sex-offender.vsp.virginia.gov/sor/policy.html')

ghost.capture_to('page.png')
```

[image: This is what I get - no images]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity:

This issue is only raised when using python 2.7. No problems if you use python 3.3.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce your issue, it worked without issue on my end. I'm using Python 3.

Comment: I just gave it a shot with python 3 and it worked. I was using 2.7.